# How to check if turtle is on stamp position

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am new to Python and trying to build a simple game. In the game is just one ant and this ant follows simple rules: if ant is on white field, he paints the tile black (or other color), turns right, moves forward. If ant is on colored tile, remove color, turn left, move forward.

Currently I am trying to do this with turtle and stamps. Stamp ID and coordinates are stored in a dict, a loop is checking if ant position is in dict keys and there is the problem: when the ant moves to the same position, where the first stamp is, this check return False and the ant never escape the loop.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(height=900, width=1000)
screen.title("The Ant")
ant = Turtle()
ant.color("brown")
ant.pencolor("black")
ant.penup()
kleks_liste = {}
game_running = True

ant.shape("square")
ant.setpos(5, 5)
kleks_liste[ant.pos()] = ant.stamp()
ant.shape("classic")
ant.forward(20)

while game_running:
    pos_key = ant.pos()
    if pos_key in kleks_liste.keys():
        ant.clearstamp(kleks_liste[pos_key])
        kleks_liste.pop(pos_key)
        ant.left(90.00)
        ant.forward(20.00)
    else:
        ant.right(90.00)
        ant.shape("square")
        kleks_liste[pos_key] = ant.stamp()
        ant.shape("classic")
        ant.forward(20.00)

screen.exitonclick()
```

What am I doing wrong? If I comment out `ant.forward` in the `else` section, the check works and returns True. Can someone explain the behavior?

Comment: This is called [Langton's ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) FYI.

Comment: Thanks for the name of this, I wasn't sure how it was called. Just searching for "Ant" was leading in wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

The Vec2D returned by `pos()` contains floats which need to be compared with an epsilon. One workaround is to cast these values to integers, either with `int` or `round`. This shouldn't lose accuracy since you're working on a grid.

Instead of `pos_key = ant.pos()`, try `pos_key = tuple(map(int, ant.pos()))`. Don't forget to change the first stamp key outside the loop too.

As an aside, you can use `if pos_key in kleks_liste:` without `.keys()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is working now, but not with  `int` . With `int` the fourth position was returned with `(4, 4)` coordinates and should be `(5, 5)`, so I had to work with `round`. However I think my Langton's ant probably will never enter the periodic state or escape it at some point, since there is a small error by every move.

Comment: Maybe you can cancel out the errors/drift over time by using a `setpos` call after every forward to clamp to integers, something like `ant.setpos(*map(int, ant.pos()))`. I doubt it matters but I'd pass integers to your movements and turns, `90` instead of `90.00`. The goal is to clamp as much to the grid as possible and avoid floats.

Comment: Another option is to keep track of your position without `pos`, computed by delta movements from the origin. So create integer variables for `x` and `y`, then when you move in a particular direction, adjust the `x` and `y` by the change on each axis corresponding to a step in that direction. Your indexes into the data structure will then be clean and unambiguous.

Comment: As mentioned before `int` returns wrong values sometimes. The Ant is working with `round()`, it also enters the periodic state, so I let it be for the time being. Passing floats to the turns and movements was an attempt to improve the behavior, it was all integers and I didn't reformat it back before asking here.

Comment: Right--the reason it sometimes returns wrong values is because the position is drifting over time, presumably due to accumulated float errors. If you use your own integer-based position tracking system and/or calls to `setpos` after every move, then you should be able to clamp it down to integers all the way and eliminate the drift. The concern with `round` is it doesn't really solve the underlying position drift problem, so after enough steps it seems likely that `round` will start to get off-grid too. I can post a proof of concept if this doesn't make sense (and I have the time).